# Javascript function code to remove zeroes in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Can you guys please help me implement a javascript function to remove zeroes which appears at any position in an array. Here is the array I have created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Zeroes</title>
<h3>Removing Zeroes from the Array</h3>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i;
var numbers = new Array();
numbers[0] = "1100";
numbers[1] = "12879081";
numbers[2] = "9916655694";
for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
document.write(numbers[i] + "<br>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You mean "1100" would be "11". Use a regular expression with replace. TADA, If you mean there would be a "0", than put one in your sample code!

Comment: I mean to say that where ever a "0" appears, It has to be deleted. 

Yes, "1100" would become "11" after a call the function to remove zeroes.

Comment: can the replace function be used on an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, use `String.replace`.

I use to create a prototype `replaceAll` in my projects. Code below. I could replace by regular expression. But, I would have to format entries with escapes ("\", "[", "]", ,etc). So, for simplicity, I use the old and nice `indexOf` + `replace`.

So all I would need is to call `.replaceAll("0", "")`:

```
var numbers = {"1100", "12879081", "9916655694"};

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    document.write(numbers[i].replaceAll("0", "") + "<br />");
}
```

Replace All:

```
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll){
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function (searchValue, replaceValue) {
        var str = this;
        while (str.indexOf(searchValue) > -1) {
            str = str.replace(searchValue, replaceValue);
        }
        return str;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a filter to filter out zero values, and since it looks like you have an array of strings, you'd have to parse it as numbers as well :

```
numbers.filter(function(v) {return parseInt(v, 10) !== 0;});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4A5S/)

or if what you really meant was to remove any zero, anywhere

```
for (i=numbers.length; i--;) {
    numbers[i] = numbers[i].replace(/0/g,'');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4A5S/1/)

Comment: Hi, could you please explain the parameter "v".

Comment: @user3091376: `console.log(v);`

Comment: The parameter `v` is the value of the currently iterated array index

Comment: @adeneo It is the second one.

Comment: can the index of function be used to create the function to remove zeroes?

Comment: @epascarello - Thanks, I added both as it was unclear ?